# Why is there the need for "return false" in my code?

Tags: javascript

I have read up on what event bubbling means and understood what it meant, but I am still unable to understand why my code requires "return false".

```
function init() {
  var fireButton = document.getElementById("fireButton");
  fireButton.onclick = handleFireButton;
  var guessInput = document.getElementById("guessInput");
  guessInput.onkeypress = handleKeyPress;
}

function handleFireButton() {
  var guessInput = document.getElementById("guessInput");
  var guess = guessInput.value;
  controller.processGuess(guess);
  guessInput.value = "";
}

function handleKeyPress(e) {
  var fireButton = document.getElementById("fireButton");
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //13 represent the "Enter" key.
    fireButton.click();
    return false;
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Perhaps elaborate why you think you do no need `false`, and what you expect to happen once an event triggers (and what happens)

Comment: The `return false` is not necessary afaict from this snip.

Comment: @apple apple 
perhaps, if you have time, can visit 
[link](https://codepen.io/JunHuiLean/pen/OqWggp), the code is not working well (always refreshes a second time) when i use "enter" to submit the results ("A0").

Comment: @JunHuiLean next time please include [mcve] in question (and not link). it's really important to make us understand what happens and can start help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an Enter button in case it is a form in a markup it may trigger submit of the form, I would suggest changing `return false;` to `e.preventDefault();` because it is much more literal at what it is doing, but that's just my opinion

Comment: Hi! Thanks! So, am i right in saying that by using e.preventDefault(), I am in a sense "disabling" the Enter button default function of submitting the form? 
Hence, allowing .onclick to work only.

Comment: In this particular case it is yes. e.preventDefault gives you ability to do only what you put into a handler and not its default behavior.

Comment: Does it answer you question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: Then you should probably mark the correct answer and close the question

Answer (score 1):

the `return false` would prevent the form from submit. You can also use `e.preventDefault()` in this case (and this is probably what you really want).

Anyway, you can simply remove the `form` tag altogether, it's not necessary. (or handle `onsubmit` instead of `onclick/onkeypress` if you want to use `form`)